# store seconde column's values of a 3*2 array (dtype=object) in a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

given the following array

```
  n=int(input())
  a=np.empty((n,2) , dtype=object)
  for i in range(n):
      a[i][0]=input() #string
      a[i][1]=input() #float
```

I want to gather all the floats in a list so I can do some operations.
Here's how I tried to do it :

```
def notes(a):
    l=[]
    for i in range(np.shape(a)[0]):
        if a[i][1] not in l:
            l.append(a[i][1])
    return lis
```

this seems logical to me, but I'm getting this error:

> for i in range(np.shape(a)[0]):
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

How can I fix this ?

Comment: It's not clear why you're using numpy for this and not standard types (e.g. `list`) -- is there a reason that the example obscures?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the provided code. I advise you to provide a code without `input()`. I advise you to print `np.shape(a)` which is likely an empty tuple due to `a` being a scalar and not a Numpy array. Besides this, the loop is not efficient as `in l` do a linear search. It seems you try to implement `np.unique` but in a far less efficient way.

Comment: It's an exercice on HackerRank. I think using numpy is necessary. [link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list) @jedwards

Comment: @JérômeRichard  
In the exercice it's required to use `input()`

Comment: @HamzaDevXX Thanks for the link, I just threw something together and can tell you that numpy _isn't_ necessary (that is, it'll accept answers without numpy as correct).

Comment: @jedwards Ok, thank you. I'll try to do it without numpy.
But I still don't understand why the previous code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `a` creation:

```
In [268]:   n=int(input())
     ...:   a=np.empty((n,2) , dtype=object)
     ...:   for i in range(n):
     ...:       a[i,0]=input() #string
     ...:       a[i,1]=input() #float
     ...: 
2
testing
1.23
foo
2.34
In [269]: a
Out[269]: 
array([['testing', '1.23'],
       ['foo', '2.34']], dtype=object)
```

If this `a` is passed to `notes` (you don't show that step), the iteration should work:

```
In [270]: a.shape
Out[270]: (2, 2)
In [271]: a.shape[0]
Out[271]: 2
In [272]: for i in range(a.shape[0]):
     ...:     print(a[i,1])
     ...: 
1.23
2.34
```

Your error suggests that you are passing a scalar to `notes`

```
In [275]: np.shape(4)[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [275] in <cell line: 1>
    np.shape(4)[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

But you don't need to iterate to get the 2nd column:

```
In [276]: a[:,1]
Out[276]: array(['1.23', '2.34'], dtype=object)
In [277]: a[:,1].astype(float)
Out[277]: array([1.23, 2.34])
In [278]: a[:,1].astype(float).tolist()
Out[278]: [1.23, 2.34]
```

Your repeated use of `a[i][0]` syntax indicates that you have not read much of the basic `numpy` documentation.  You are treating `a` as a nested list.  `a[i,0]` is a more idiomatic way of indexing a 2d array.

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved my problem. Indeed, I will revise the basic numpy documentation.